# Как проверить, что программа успешно вошла в почту

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Как проверить и вывести в консоль, что программа успешно вошла в почту?

И наоборот: если авторизация не удалась, то также вывести в консоль.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://account.mail.ru/login')
sleep(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('Login')
elem.send_keys(LOGIN)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/button')
elem.click()
sleep(3)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('Password')
elem.send_keys(password)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/button')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(3)
```

Comment: А зачем входить в почту через Selenium, чем IMAP не угодил?

Comment: Хочу реализовать это все через селениум